# asp.net TemplateField.ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, templates

```
TemplateField tf1 = new TemplateField(); 
tf1.ItemTemplate = ???
```

How to initialize this property?

If I need to this programmatically then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually do this sort of thing in the markup:

```
<TemplateField ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox .../>
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

or do the same thing using the designer.

---

Example follows. The commented-out markup produces the same thing as the codebehind does:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorksConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Person.Contact.FirstName, Person.Contact.LastName 
        FROM Person.Contact 
        INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee ON Person.Contact.ContactID = HumanResources.Employee.ContactID 
        WHERE (Person.Contact.LastName LIKE N'A%') 
        ORDER BY Person.Contact.LastName, Person.Contact.FirstName">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<%--        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLast">Name:&nbsp;</asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName")+", "+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>--%>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <hr />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Repeater1.ItemTemplate = new TheItemTemplate();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}

public class TheItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    #region Implementation of ITemplate

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        var lblLast = new Label {ID = "lblLast", Text = "Name: "};
        container.Controls.Add(lblLast);

        var lblName = new Label {ID = "lblName"};
        lblName.DataBinding += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                               {
                                   var theLabel = (Label) sender;
                                   var dataItem = DataBinder.GetDataItem(theLabel.BindingContainer);
                                   theLabel.Text = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "LastName") + ", " +
                                                   DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "FirstName");
                               };
        container.Controls.Add(lblName);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If I need to this programmatically then what to do?

Comment: Initialize it to an instance of a class that implements `ITemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TemplateField tf1 = new TemplateField(); 
tf1.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("ItemTemplate.ascx");
```

Comment: I need to put any regular asp.net control like Label/TextBox. Not user-controls.

Comment: You can add your Label/Textbox or whatever other controls you need to the User Control.